# ImmutableJS: Removing repeated values from list

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have the following example list:

```
let fruits = Immutable.fromJS(['apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'fidgy', 'grape', 'melon', 'watermelon', 'watermelon']);
```

I couldn't find in documentation any function from removing all repeated values. How can I do this? Is it performatic?

The output I want is: `['apple', 'banana', 'fidgy', 'grape', 'melon', 'watermelon']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally if you have a dataset where you don't want duplicates, you'd use a `Set` rather than a general sequence. In your case, the easiest thing to do would be to do

```
let fruits = Immutable.Set(['apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'fidgy', 'grape', 'melon', 'watermelon', 'watermelon']);
```

Comment: @loganfsmyth I've found that actually using Sets works, but Sets doesn't have *split* function, so I have to create a Immutable List from splitting and then convert it back to a CommonJS list, and then use this as an argument for creating a Immutable Set. Is it performatic, or there is any better way of doing it?

Comment: Yup, my mistake. `.fromKeys` is not needed.